# What is wrong with my use of jsonkit decode in objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, json, jsonkit

I have a file:

```
{
    "MapName" : "This is map1";
}
```

Which I try to read in with:

```
- (id)initFromFile:(NSString *)mapName
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:mapName ofType:@"json"];
        NSData* jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
        assert(jsonData);
        JSONDecoder* decoder = [[JSONDecoder alloc]
                                initWithParseOptions:JKParseOptionNone];
        assert(decoder);

        NSDictionary* json = (NSDictionary*)[decoder objectWithData:jsonData];

        assert(json);

        NSString* mapName = (NSString*)[json objectForKey:@"MapName"];

        assert(mapName);

        printf("MapName: %s\n", [mapName UTF8String]);
    }

    return self;
}
```

Which fails at assert(json);
Is there anything obvious i'm doing wrong?

I know the file is being read ok but the decode is passing back NULL.

Thanks

Comment: Eugene was very close:

    {
        "MapName" : "This is map1"
    }

No delimiter on last item. Comma should be used on all previous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use comma instead of semicolon

```
{
    "MapName" : "This is map1",
}
```

Validate here jsonlint.com

Comment: Close. Thanks for giving me the idea to check the json. I should have have no mark as it's the last one in the collection. So no comma or semi-column.